# Use Spring ressource bundle with Hibernate Validator

Tags: java, spring, validation, hibernate-validator, tomcat8

First time posting here.

I'm developing a JSON webservice API and I'm tring to use custom validation message with no success.

Here is my setup (focus on component involved in my problem. I also use MyBatis, jUnit...) :

- Tomcat 8.0.14
- Spring 4.1.1
- Jersey 2.13
- Jersey-spring3 2.13
- Jersey-bean-validation
- Hibernate Validator 5.0.0.Final

Bean property validation and class-level validation work fine.
Now I'm trying to setup custom error validation messages.

I don't wan't to use the JSR-303 /META-INF/ValidationMessages.properties but I wan't to use a spring managed bundle.

In my applicationContext.xml, I defined :

```
<bean name="validator" class="org.springframework.validation.beanvalidation.LocalValidatorFactoryBean">
    <property name="validationMessageSource">
        <ref bean="messageSource" />
    </property>
</bean>

<bean name="messageSource"
    class="org.springframework.context.support.ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource">
    <property name="basename" value="configuration/messages/validation" />
</bean>
```

I also create a /WEB-INF/classes/configuration/messages/validation_fr_FR.properties with some properties :

```
model.error=Modèle invalide
```

Now when I try to validate my Bean I get this in my logs :

```
15:47:14,300 DEBUG http-nio-8080-exec-2 resourceloading.PlatformResourceBundleLocator:72 - ValidationMessages not found.
15:47:45,707 DEBUG http-nio-8080-exec-2 resourceloading.PlatformResourceBundleLocator:69 - org.hibernate.validator.ValidationMessages found.
```

No mention to my bundle here...

In my JSON response, I get :

```
{model.error} (path = EventServiceAPIImpl.createOrUpdateEvent.arg0, invalidValue = fr.bz.pdcv.bean.Event@d99af88)
```

{model.error} is not replaced with my custom message.

I think my ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource is overridden by Hibernate Validator default configuration. But why ?

I overload google and stackoverflow to find a solution, I didn't find anythings which can help me

Does someone encounter the same issue ?

Thank you !

Comment: I'm too late to your question. But most likely the issue is you are not able to tell the Hibernate Validator what your Locale is. Also by default en_US locale is used by the hibernate validator. So most likely hibernate validator is not able to find the default locale related validationMessage hence you are seeing the error.

Answer (score 0):

Though I guess i am late but it may help someone else.

Rename your **validation_fr_FR.properties** with **ValidationMessages.properties** file and put that inside the folder '**src\main\resources**'.

So your final path will be as follows:

> *src\main\resources\ValidationMessages.properties*

Restart the server and try to render the validation.

U no more need the *LocalValidatorFactoryBean* and *ResourceBundleMessageSource*

Hibernate basically looks for the same file name in the default directory and overwrites the default *ValidationMessages.properties*